# Recurrent Error when updating products in Magento Db

Tags: permissions

Wondering what this error could be in 1.9.3.6 cms:

*The db field size is 'nn' bytes to small to save the group permissions. Please enable the configuration setting to dynamicaly grow the field length and try again.*

and if it will affect the day to day operation of my Magento store?

It occurs after every product save.

My changes seem to stick and are visible on the front end.

Regards

Jim

Comment: do you have any modules for per customer group permissions ?

Comment: Yes, I was using netzarbeiter groups catalogue to set up customers on the site on 1.7 thru to 1.9.3.2. but the last update to 1.9.3.6 seems to have rendered that invisible. A developer ran the upgrade for me alongside some patches.

Comment: The problem lies with this module. Try disabling it

Answer (score 0):

To enable *the setting* as described in the warning message for the module *Netzarbeiter_GroupsCatalog*, go to admin > System > Configuration > CATALOG / Catalog > Customer Groups Catalog > set **Grow DB Field Size if required** to *Yes*